# Numpy array splitting in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a csv file that I have inputted using `genfromtxt`

```
csv_file = np.genfromtxt(args.dataset, delimiter=',',skip_header=1,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5), dtype=None)
```

`print(csv_file)` gives following output:

```
array([('X1.png', 'class1', 698, 333, 710, 358),
       ('X2.png', 'class2', 846, 391, 858, 411),
       ('X3.png', 'class3', 698, 337, 710, 357), ...,
       ('Xn.png', 'class4', 126,  95, 198, 225),
       ('Xn+1.png', 'class5',  74, 109, 143, 219),
       ('Xn+2.png', 'class3',  16, 104,  88, 224)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S32'), ('f1', 'S11'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<i8'), ('f4', '<i8'), ('f5', '<i8')])

>>> img_name = csv_file[1]
>>> img_name
('x.png', 'class', 846, 391, 858, 411)
>>> type(img_name)
<type 'numpy.void'>
```

Question: I would like to split each row in csv_file to different columns in a array(say Y) ?

Comment: Could you install `pandas` ?   That package builds on `numpy` to offer next-level support for this kind of thing.

Comment: This is structured array. You can index each 'column' by field name. e.g `csv_file['f0']`. Index by number gives a row record.  `csv_file[0]['f1']` should be 'class1'.

Comment: No, I wanted to reduce the number packages that I use

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks your method works....

Comment: @hpaulj how to use two or more columns together

Comment: `arr[['f0', 'f2']]` selects columns.  I.e. use a list of field names.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html

Comment: Thanks....please write as a answer I will accept it